# How to say "A wants B to keep away from C."?

Tags: grammar

I want to say

> A wants B to keep away from C. (A is a third person)

My attempt is as follows,

> AはBにCを遠ざけてほしがっている。

Is it correct? Unnatural? Any comment and suggestion is really appreciated.

Comment: It's basically 「AはBにCから離れていてほしい」and the ending expression may vary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it would literally be like 「AはBにCから遠ざかっていてほしがっている」 or 「AはBにCから離れていてほしがっている」, but they don't sound very natural, so how about:

> AはBをCに近づけたがらない。/ 近寄らせたがらない。
>   AはBにCに近づかないで(いて)ほしがっている。 / 近寄らないで(いて)ほしがっている。

or maybe:

> AはBにCに近づいてほしくないと思っている。 / 近寄ってほしくないと思っている。
>   AはBにCに近づかないで(いて)ほしいと思っている。 / 近寄らないで(いて)ほしいと思っている。

... etc., depending on the context.

Comment: If A is a third person, the ending must be …たがって…, right?

Comment: @YasashiiEirian そうですね・・・長くなってしまうので、「～たがらない。」とかのほうがいいかも。

Comment: Do you regularly check your email?

Comment: Oh! Not really... hehe..

Comment: I see. Hehehe...

Answer (score 2):

I would say "A wants B to keep away from C." as "AはBにC から遠ざかって(Cに近づかないで、Cと絶縁して、Cと手を切って）欲しいと思っている。

Please note that you need to choose the right particle after C. according to the context

Comment: Particles do not inflect in Japanese.