# Can we use 近づける without an explicit object?

Tags: grammar

近づける is a transitive verb.

- X: 僕は子供を池に近づけない。I keep away the children from the pond.

But there is a case in which 近づける is used without an object as the following sentence quoted from [another answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/34259/11192).

- Y: AはBにCに近づいてほしくないと思っている。A wants B to keep away from C.

## Questions

When there is no explicit object given for 近づける, do we have to assume the object is actually the same as the subject?

It means Y can be rewritten as

- Z: AはBに**Bを**Cに近づいてほしくないと思っている。A wants B to keep away B from C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

近づける is transitive, and its intransitive counterpart is 近づく. The te-form of 近づける is 近づ**け**(-て), while the te-form of 近づく is 近づ**い**(-て).

Sentence Y uses this *intransitive* version, in its te-form. No wonder it doesn't require a direct object.

Sentence Z hardly makes sense to me, but compare the following two sentences, which are very similar in meaning.

- **Y:** AはBにCに近づ**い**てほしくないと思っている。 A wants B to keep away from C.
- **Z2:** AはBにCを近づ**け**てほしくないと思っている。 A wants B to keep C away.